# I made install for express, mongoose and body-parser. but When I am trying to install 'ejs' the error below running!. how can I solve it?

Tags: node.js, npm, ejs

[The error I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzWn8.png)

Also this is package.json I have
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZCQQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you already have some packages installed and want to install another package alongside the rest, You use the *--save* at the end.

*--save* looks for an already existing **package.json** file and updates it.

```
npm install ejs --save
```

Comment: It did not solved the problem. I tried it before.